# Full flag $Fl_{\mathbb C}(3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, group-actions, grassmannian

How we can see that the full complex flag when $n=3$ is equivalent to one of these spaces:

- $\{(u,v)\in \mathbb CP^2\times \mathbb CP^2 ; u\perp v\}$ and what is dimension over $\mathbb C$ here?
- $\{(l,W); l\in Gr(1,3),W\in Gr(2,3),l\subset W\}$?

I know that the full flag $Fl_{\mathbb C}(3)= U(3)/(\mathbb S^1)^{\times 3}$ but I can't deduce that is the same as above spaces (or at least one of them)!

Comment: The second space is what is usually taken to be the _definition_ of the space of full flags.

Comment: But the definition I use is that the full flag is the space of all sequences $\{0\}=V_0 \subset V_1\subset...\subset V_n=\mathbb C^n$ with $dim V_j=j $ How we can see that both definitions are equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

The right space is the second!

For completeness, let $\mathbb{V}$ be a complex vector space of dimension $n$; I recall that a *flag* of $\mathbb{V}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of vector subspaces of $\mathbb{V}$
$$
\{\underline{0}\}=\mathbb{V}_0<\mathbb{V}_1<\dots<\mathbb{V}_r\leq\mathbb{V}\,\text{where:}\,\forall i\in\{1,\dots,r\},\dim\mathbb{V}_i=m_i,\,dim\mathbb{V}_{i\displaystyle/\mathbb{V}_{i-1}}=d_i,
$$
the $r$-tuple $(m_1,\dots,m_r)$ is called *signature of the flag*; and if the signature is $(1,\dots,n)$ then the flag is called *complete*.

Let $\mathcal{F}(n;m_1,\dots,m_r)$ be the set of the  flags of $\mathbb{V}$ with signature $(m_1,\dots,m_r)$, let $F\in\mathcal{F}(n;m_1,\dots,m_r)$; by definition:
$$
F\equiv\mathbb{V}_0<\mathbb{V}_1<\mathbb{V}_2<\dots<\mathbb{V}_r\leq\mathbb{V}
$$
and let $\{e_1\dots,e_n\}$ be a basis of $\mathbb{V}$ such that:
$$
\forall i\in\{1,\dots,r\},\,\mathbb{V}_i=\langle e_1,\dots,e_{m_i}\rangle;
$$
then $\forall M\in\mathrm{GL}(n,\,\mathbb{C}),i\in\{1,\dots,r\},\,M\cdot\mathbb{V}_i=\langle M\cdot e_1,\dots,M\cdot e_{m_i}\rangle$ are well defined subspaces of $\mathbb{V}$; in particular, the flag
$$
\mathcal{F}(n;m_1,\dots,m_r)\ni M\cdot F\equiv\mathbb{V}_0< M\cdot\mathbb{V}_1<\dots<M\cdot\mathbb{V}_r\leq\mathbb{V}
$$
is well defined.

After all this, one can define the action
$$
\alpha:(M,F)\in\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})\times\mathcal{F}(n;m_1,\dots,m_r)\to M\cdot F\in\mathcal{F}(n;m_1,\dots,m_r);
$$
one (easily) prove that $\alpha$ is a transitive action and therefore $\mathcal{F}(n;m_1,\dots,m_r)$ is in bijection with
$$
\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})_{\displaystyle/P(d_1,\dots,d_r)},
$$
where $P(d_1,\dots,d_r)$ is the (closed) subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ generated by the matrices of the following type
$$
\forall i\leq j\in\{1,\dots,r\},\,A_i^j\in\mathbb{C}_{d_i}^{d_j},\,\begin{pmatrix}
A_1^1 & A_1^2 & \dots & A_1^r\\
\underline{0}_{d_2}^{d_1} & A_2^2 & \dots & A_2^r\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\underline{0}_{d_r}^{d^1} & \underline{0}_{d_r}^{d_2} & \dots & A_r^r
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
In particular, one can restrict the focus on the isometries of $\mathbb{V}$; one can define the action
$$
\widetilde{\alpha}:(M,F)\in\mathrm{U}(n)\times\mathcal{F}(n;m_1,\dots,m_r)\to M\cdot F\in\mathcal{F}(n;m_1,\dots,m_r)
$$
and as for $\alpha$, one prove that $\widetilde{\alpha}$ is a transitive action and therefore $\mathcal{F}(n;m_1,\dots,m_r)$ is in bijection with
$
\mathrm{U}(n)_{\displaystyle/\mathrm{U}(d_1)\times\dots\mathrm{U}(d_r)}$.

Is it all clear?

Furthermore: the first space is the space of *(complete) orthogonal flag* $\mathcal{F}^{\perp}(3;1,2,3)$ *of* $\mathbb{C}^3$.

Comment: We can associate a unique orthonormal basis to any complete flag by the Gram-Schmidt process, so, is "the space of complete orthogonal flags" really different from the space of complete flags?

Comment: They are different as sets.

Comment: But homeomorphic? @Armando j18eos

Comment: @テレビスクリーン If I am not wrong: these spaces are diffeomorphic as real manifolds!